# react-router-config - multiple path for one component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react-router-config package from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-config for my project. I created a Routes.js file where I set my routes configurations, it looks like this:

```
    export default [
    {
        ...App,
        routes: [
            {
                ...IndexPage,
                path: '/',
                exact: true
            },
            {
                ...CategoryPage,
                path: '/computers'
            },
            {
                ...CategoryPage,
                path: '/home'
            },
            {
                ...NotFoundPage
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

as you can see I use two paths '/computers' and '/home' to load the same component **CategoryPage**. I wonder if it possible to pass multiple paths in one object to load the same component, something like this:

```
{
  ...CategoryPage,
  path: ['/computers','/home']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

base on the documentation https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/Glossary.md#path 
path  type is a string but when I read this update, I guess it's support for react router version 4.4
 [https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string-string][1]

In this example
`<Route path={["/users/:id", "/profile/:id"]} component={User} />`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I think the way you wrote might be the way. You could first create your ideal structure, ex.

```
{
   components: [...CategoryPage],
   path: ['/computers','/home']
}
```

And then use your own utility function to transform it into your final structure. This way you can make your routing structure as flexible as you want and one source of data at the same time. I found thinking this way is more scalable than bending the routing default structure.